# Code style of method chaining within Zend

Tags: zend-framework

this has previously been asked here (http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-11135) with no response from Zend so really it has to come down to popular or majority decision.

The reason I am asking is because the company that I work for are increasing in size and having a standard style is obviously a sensible approach.

One example that is ignored from the example linked above is multiple methods per line, I.e

```
$this->setAction()->setMethod()->etc()
    ->etc()->andSoForth();
```

Which assists in the compliance of line length.

So whats your personal opinion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method chaining can get a little hard to follow on long lines, but if you add a return before each method call then it is perfectly readable and saves repetitively typing the class variable.

Regarding the question asked at http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-11135 - the first and second code examples are identical - should they be showing a difference?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Please accept my apologies I actually posted the wrong link :) The first example is method chaining on multiple lines and the second example if ensuring that each method call is always returned to the next line.